# myArray doesnt exist?

Tags: arrays, processing

I am trying to initialise an array that holds 3 values, the x and y coordinates of a rectangle and whether or not it is visible on screen to do this i have written this code:

```java
void rupee() {
  int [] [] myArray = { {200, 110, 1}, {290, 110, 1}, {380, 200, 1}, {470, 110, 1}, {560, 110, 1}, {650, 200, 1}, {110, 200, 1}, {110, 290, 1}, {110, 380, 1}, {200, 470, 1}, {290, 560, 1}, {380, 650, 1}, {470, 560, 1}, {560, 470, 1}, {560, 470, 1}, {650, 380, 1}, {650, 290, 1} };
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
      rect(myArray(i,i), myArray(j,j),50,50);
    }
  }
}
```

i am getting this error under both `myArray`"The function "myArray(int,int)" does not exist.

Comment: you don't access a two-dimensional array like that. it should be--> `rect(myArray[i][i], myArray[j][j],50,50);`. you should have a look at [Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Java](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html).

Comment: @Aominè thanks, now im getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 error, i have changed 16 and 3 to one less and one more but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  make use of the `length` property. I am not sure what you want your end result to be but here is an example of how to use the `length` property. `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
     
    }
  }`

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to access `myArray` with a wrong syntax. try `myArray[i][j]` ...